# Grabbing a body of text using regex excluding specific conditions

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm using Python regex to grab the body of a parsed email which may contain nothing or may look something like this:

> Some coherent sentence.
>
> lalskjfa;ljkd
>
> the other stuff
>
> ---
>
> A couple of lines of email signature blah blah
>
> blah blah blah
>
> ---

I want everything in that body of the email EXCLUDING the signature line opener and its contents.

I'm basically tearing out everything but that signature email in order to reformat it for reporting.

I've tried:

- negative lookahead: `\G(\A\z|.*\n*(?!_))`
- positive lookahead: `\G(\A\z|.*\n*(?=_))`

Neither seems to be doing the trick.

With a negative lookahead, it seems to be grabbing everything. With a positive lookahead, it seems to be grabbing nothing.

The output I'm hoping to achieve is this text:

> Some coherent sentence.
>
> lalskjfa;ljkd
>
> the other stuff

Comment: Maybe `re.search(r'(?sm)\A(.*?)\n_+$', text).group(1)`? I would not use a regex if this regex "works". You may just read all lines till a line containing only underscores.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Due to the way this process is built out, I can't access the python group(1) without changing a lot of the guts of our program, which I'm not keen on messing around with.

Comment: Its all about delimiters. If it's a double quote then `".*?"` But it's not good to go with the number of LF's etc.. which is a very poor delimiter.

Comment: Thanks to your helpful hint, though, I was able to try this: ```(?sm)\A(.*?)\n(?=_)``` and it seems to be grabbing what I need.

Comment: what is the role of _ here

Comment: It is just a style separator for the signature line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(?s)\A.*?(?=\n_)
```

It matches

- `(?s)` - `re.DOTALL` inline flag
- `\A` - start of string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible till the first occurrence of
- `(?=\n_)` - a newline followed with `_` char.