# How to regex to avoid the last matched string

Tags: python, regex

wrote a regex to get the character till the the searched one. Here till `#` i need to extract

```
import re
text = '''text1
text2
text3
#text4
text5'''
print(re.search('(?s)\A.*?(\#)', text))
```

My Out

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 19), match='text1\ntext2\ntext3\n#'>
```

Expected

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 19), match='text1\ntext2\ntext3'>
```

Comment: Use a lookahead instead: `(?=\n#)`

Comment: Please stop logging from various accounts, [the answer is already given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738970/grabbing-a-body-of-text-using-regex-excluding-specific-conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply a case of using a positive look-ahead `(?=#)`. Use the below pattern:

```
(?s)\A.*(?=\#)
```

Comment: (?s)\A.*(?#) why this regex not working ?# has greedy match right?

Comment: @cdac [**The answer is here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738970/grabbing-a-body-of-text-using-regex-excluding-specific-conditions)

Comment: What you have above is different to what I posted. I'm not even sure why you put the `?` before the hash without something to define it (it's an incorrect pattern). `?` before the parentheses just means you can have 0 to unlimited 1 or none times...